# Conceptual problem regarding distance between two sets.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $(X,d)$ and two non empty subsets $A,B \subset X$ we define the distance between $A$ and $B$ as 
$$
d(A,B) = \inf\, \{d(a,b) : a\in A, b\in B\}
$$

My question is the following:  when trying to solve problems regarding this distance, many times, when for example $d(A,B)=0$, I arrive to the following fact, since $d(A,B) \in \mathbb{R}$, there exist a sequence $((d(a_{n},b_{n}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_{n} \in A$, $b_{n} \in B$ and $d(a_{n},b_{n})\rightarrow 0$. This makes me arise to the following question which is driving me mad: This implies that $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ both converge, (of course to the same limit)?

I am not being able to prove this fact, nor find a counter example (I am really bad at finding counter examles) If someone could clarify this to me, I would REALLY apreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual metric.

Take $A = \{(x,e^x) \}_{x \in \mathbb{R}}, B= \{ (x,-e^x) \}_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$.

Then $d(A,B) = 0$ as is seen by the sequences $a_n = (-n, e^{-n}), b_n = (-n, -e^{-n})$, but clearly neither sequence converges.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n=\lim_{n\to\infty} n-\frac1n=\infty$$

But $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n-\left(n-\frac1n\right)\right)=0.$$

Comment: @Jas, the fact that $d(A,B)$ is an $infimum$ (in $\mathbb{R}$) implies that there is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ that converges to the $infimum$.

Answer (score 0):

When you say $d(A, B)=inf\{d(a, b): a\in A, b\in B\}$, you are looking at the $inf$ of a set and not a sequence.This is where you're making a mistake. Basically, what this means is that the distance between two sets is defined as the distance between their two closest points. If you will, you are looking at all the possible distances $d(a_{i}, b_{i})$ where $i\in I$, for some index set $I$. But in case that doesn't make sense to you, disregard the last part there so you don't get confused.